# How to name written data that it will likely be used later in the project?

Tags: planning, documentation

How can I give a general name for documented data that will likely to be accessed and used in the future? Data like:

- outline of summary of a meeting.
- a list of links, found after a research session.
- a mind-map file of a brainstorming session.
- an excel tracking sheet.
- a google sheets inventory list.

To differentiate from other data that is also related to the project- tasks, goals, dates, team members, etc.

We want to figure this out in order to name a database that will be responsible for that.
We thought of the name **Resources** but it collides with a different meaning in PM.

Answer (score 1):

Could be:

- Objectives
- Assets
- Operations
- Data